# P NP R RE closures

Tags: complexity-theory, computability, np, closure-properties, recursively-enumerable

I wrote the following table for all the closures in those classes.

is anything there incorrect?

also, would appreciate help with coNP and coRE closures. couldn't find much information about it online.

[image]

Comment: I believe RE is closed under reversal, if that's what $A^R$ means. Can't you just the reverse input before running the original algorithm? Additionally, for $A\triangle B$ I believe it's unknown whether NP is closed to it, since it is if $P = NP$ and isn't if $NP \neq coNP$

Comment: @CommandMaster thanks, I missed the reversal of RE, you're right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

updated table:

[image]

"?" means it's an open question (unkonwn)